# C++, templatize pointer to a function

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

There are two pointers to different functions

```
typedef std::vector<double> TData;
double ( * p_test1 ) ( const TData> &arg);
double ( * p_test2 ) ( const TData> &ar1, char *arg2, char *arg3);
```

and a method which has as an argument a pointer to the function

```
double f (double ( * p_test1 ) ( const TData  &arg ))
{
    //Long and not trivial algorithm processing results of p_test
    for ( i = 0;... )
    {
       double res = p_test (arg);  //Some computations
    }
}
```

The f() method contains difficult calculations (here replaced by a for cycle).

Is it possible to templatize this argument (i.e., pointer to a function having different amount of parameters) to get a general function processing both types arguments

```
double f (double ( * p_test1 ) ( const TData  &arg ));
double f (double ( * p_test2 ) ( const TData> &ar1, char *arg2, char *arg3));
```

Or is there any way how to write such a function, for example to write a pointer to a pointer to the function?

I would like to avoid the partial specialization of f() function because of its complexity (repetitively overwritten of the long code  is not efficient).

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Rather than bother with function pointers, wouldn't it be easier to simply create some function objects with `operator()` overloaded to provide the interface you want? The main issue though, as Kerrek SB points out, is the context in which you're calling the functions.

Comment: @ Component 10 May I ask you for a short code sample? Thanks.

Comment: Problem is that a function with 1 argument needs to be called with 1 argument and function with 3 needs to be called with 3. So either the implementations need to be different, or you need to pack the arguments, which is best done by wrapping the pointer in a functor (perhaps using `boost::bind` or similar).

Comment: @justik: I could but I don't think it would really help, otherwise I would have done so as an answer. I tend to prefer function objects as they make code a lot clearer. However the problem here is not your function pointers, but how you intend to *call* functions which have different signatures in a (presumably) polymorphic manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method that can take *anything* can, as a special case, also take function pointer. E.g.

```
template<typename Function>
double f (Function p_test)
{ ...
    // if p_test is a function pointer or has operator(), this will work
    double res = p_test (arg);
  ... }
```

The problem however gets down to the fact, that the two functions are taking different arguments. So the arguments either have to come somehow bundled to `f`, there need to be several different implementations anyway, or the arguments will always be the same.

To bundle the arguments, usual method is to use `std::bind` (C++11) or [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/libs/bind/bind.html). Say you have a function that needs 3 arguments (`test2`) and need to pass it to generic algorithm (`f`) that will only provide the first. And you know the other 2. So you do:

```
f(bind(&test2, _1, secondarg, thirdarg))
```

(In C++11 `bind` is `std::bind` and `_1` is `std::placeholders::_1`, in Boost `bind` is `boost::bind` and `_1` is in anonymous namespace provided by the header.) In this case `f` needs to take any argument, because the return type of `bind` is unspecified class type with appropriate `operator()`.

Comment: @ Jan Hudec Is there any acceptable solution for C++ 03 (without Boost)?

Comment: @justik: You can write the wrapper functors yourself. If you only need a few cases, it's just a structure with the inner functor, the bound arguments and `operator()` which forwards appropriate combination of arguments to the inner functor/function pointer. If you wanted the general solution, I suggest you just take it out of boost (you can copy it out if you want; there is even a tool to do that, bcp).

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly write a template, at least in C++11:

```
template <typename ...Args>
double f(double(*fp)(Args...))
{
    double res = fp( /* ??? */ );
}
```

The question is: how do you know how to *call* the function?

Comment: @ Kerrek: And in older versions of C++, is there any solution? There are not many cases to solve (2 or 3), if/else construction can take this function.

Comment: @justik: You can write a couple of templates for zero, one, two... arguments. It should be a matter of simple copy-paste.

Comment: @ Kerrek. Yes, it is possible. But I do not want modify the code inside f() function... Maybe if/else statement to call a different fp().

Comment: @justik: That rapidly starts to make no sense. If you've got a finite number of if/else branches (say 5), with 5 different calls to `fp`, then you can turn that into 5 template specializations that each call `fp` once.

Comment: @ MSalters There is a big problem: algorithm inside f is not trivial. I found its repeatedly overwritten implementation (5 times) not effective.

Comment: @justik: I don't think there's a lot more for us to say until you provide more details of what you're trying to achieve. The example you've given is simply not representative of the actual needs you appear to have. Try coming up with a simple, but *representative* example so we can see what you're after.

Comment: @ MSalters: I updated my question... It is not possible to bring the real data and algorithm, the solution takes thousands of lines of the source code...

Comment: @justik: There's a difference between "your real code" and a "representative example" -- figure out what's the core of your problem, and make a **minimal** example that demonstrates precisely that problem, no more and no less. For example, your code is missing crucial details, such as where the `arg` in the body comes from.